# Qué diferencia hay entre utilizar config() y env() en Laravel

Tags: laravel

En el archivo .env tenemos todas las variables de entorno, por ejemplo:

```
APP_NAME=AppName
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=jdjkgdsjhgksjhgksjd
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://app-name.test
```

Y en la carpeta config tenemos el archivo app.php donde se hace referencia a estas variables:

```
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development')
```

Ahora bien, en el desarrollo puedo acceder a dichas variables ya sea con:

```
config('app.name', 'Laravel')
```

o también:

```
env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel')
```

Tiendo a creer que lo correcto es acceder desde config, pero hay diferencia? o sólo es una convención? porqué utilizaría una o la otra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Con respecto a `env(...)`

Puedes hacer un comando de prueba en tu `routes/console.php` con

```
Artisan::command('printenv {variable}', function (string $variable): void {
   dump(sprintf("env('%s') es '%s'", $variable, env($variable)));
});
```

Como ya viste, la función `env(...)` lee del entorno. Qué hay en el entorno? Puedes verlo ejecutando

```
  $ /usr/bin/env

    LC_ALL=...
    PATH=...
    USER=fabianm
    HOME=/home/fabianm
```

Hay muchas variables. Usando el comando que puse al principio, prueba entonces

```
  $ php artisan printenv HOME
    
    env('HOME') es '/home/fabianm'
```

Además de las variables que ya están en el entorno, puedes definir variables en el mismo comando:

```
  $ PRUEBA=123 php artisan printenv PRUEBA
    
    env('PRUEBA') es '123'
```

Y en el caso de Laravel, como en el de otras librerías que usan alguna lógica para parsear un archivo tipo dotenv, también éste se considera como origen:

```
# Contenido .env
APP_NAME=EjemploEnv

$ php artisan printenv APP_NAME
    
  env('APP_NAME') es 'EjemploEnv'
```

Estas tres fuentes de entorno tienen la misma prioridad con que las enumeré, de manera que sin importar lo que diga el archivo dotenv, la que pasas explícitamente tiene prioridad:

```
  $ APP_NAME=OtroNombre php artisan printenv APP_NAME
    
    env('APP_NAME') es 'OtroNombre'
```

También se puede usar un archivo dotenv distinto al default `.env` definiendo una variable de entorno `APP_ENV` cuyo valor corresponda al "apellido" de un archivo. ¿No se entendió? Mejor con un ejemplo:

```
# Contenido .env.prueba
APP_NAME=EjemploEnv con .env.prueba


$ APP_ENV=prueba php artisan printenv APP_NAME

  env('APP_NAME') es 'EjemploEnv con .env.prueba'
```

Y lo mismo con

```
$ php artisan printenv APP_NAME --env=prueba
```

#### Con respecto a config(...)

El uso de variables de entorno está muy bien y es el cimiento para toda configuración más sofisticada. Esas sofisticaciones son necesarias, por ejemplo, porque no existe el concepto de arreglos o hashes en las variables de entorno. Para agrupar variables en un conjunto discernible usarías un prefijo de texto y eso es impráctico.

Pensemos en variables de entorno definidas como:

```
  PROJECT_ORG='fabianm'
  PROJECT_NAME='prueba'
  PROJECT_REPO_URL=https://github.com/fabianm/prueba
```

Y un archivo `config/project.php` que dice:

```
 <?php

   return [
      'org' => env('PROJECT_ORG'),
      'name' => env('PROJECT_NAME', env('APP_NAME')),
      'repo' => [
        'url' => env('PROJECT_REPO_URL')
      ]
   ];
```

Me hago un comando para dumpear los contenidos:

```
// en routes/console.php
Artisan::command('printconfig {variable}', function (string $variable): void {
    dump([sprintf("config('%s')", $variable) => config($variable)]);
});
```

Y ahora

```
$  php artisan printconfig project

array:1 [
  "config('project')" => array:3 [
    "org" => "fabianm"
    "name" => "prueba"
    "repo" => array:1 [
      "url" => "https://github.com/fabianm/prueba"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Y también

```
$  php artisan printconfig project.repo

array:1 [
  "config('project.repo')" => array:1 [
    "url" => "https://github.com/fabianm/prueba"
  ]
]
```

Solamente tuve que declarar un array dentro de la carpeta config y en adelante pude acceder al contenido de éste recursivamente, todo en un namespace (project) que impide la colisión con configuraciones de otros paquetes.

#### Cuándo usar cada uno?

Cuando se ejecuta

```
  php artisan config:cache  # opcionalmente con --env=<ambiente>
```

Todo lo que se ha declarado como arrays en la carpeta `config` (y que es en definitiva el mapeo entre las variables de entorno y la configuración) se guarda en caché. (puedes ver su contenido en `bootstrap/cache/config.php`).

Una vez que existe una configuración en caché, el contenido de tu archivo `.env` **no se vuelve a tomar en cuenta**. La función `env(...)` podrá seguir accediendo a las variables existentes, pero no a las que están en los archivos dotenv.

```
  $ php artisan printenv HOME  # esta sigue accesible
    
    env('HOME') es '/home/fabianm'


  $ php artisan printenv APP_NAME  # esta ya no se toma en cuenta
    
    env('APP_NAME') es ''
```

Por las ventajas de mantener la configuración anidada, y porque la naturaleza de las variables parseadas del archivo dotenv no es apta para usarlas en tiempo de ejecución (en el sentido que pueden no poblarse) la práctica recomendada es siempre usar `config(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Encuentro esta respuesta en la documentación:

> Su archivo .env no debe estar comprometido con el control de código fuente de su aplicación, ya que cada desarrollador / servidor que use su aplicación podría requerir una configuración de entorno diferente. Además, esto sería un riesgo de seguridad en caso de que un intruso obtenga acceso a su repositorio de control de fuente, ya que cualquier credencial confidencial quedaría expuesta.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration